# Avoid exposing private member variables in hpp files

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have implemented a class `buffer_manager`. The purpose of this class it to provide a buffer for my `udp_client` and `tcp_client` applications.

buffer_manager.hpp

```
#ifndef BUFFER_MANAGER_H
#define BUFFER_MANAGER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>


class buffer_manager
{
public:
    typedef boost::array<unsigned char, 4096> m_array_type;
    buffer_manager();
    ~buffer_manager();
    void message_buffer(m_array_type &recv_buf);
    buffer_manager::m_array_type & get_recieve_array();
    std::string & get_message_string();

private:
  std::string m_message;
  m_array_type m_recv_buf;
};

#endif //BUFFER_MANAGER_H
```

buffer_manager.cpp

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/hex.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include "buffer_manager.hpp"

buffer_manager::buffer_manager()
{

}
buffer_manager::~buffer_manager()
{

}
void buffer_manager::message_buffer(m_array_type &recv_buf)
{
    boost::algorithm::hex(recv_buf.begin(), recv_buf.end(), back_inserter(m_message));
}

buffer_manager::m_array_type& buffer_manager::get_recieve_array()
{
  return m_recv_buf;
}

std::string & buffer_manager::get_message_string()
{
  return m_message;
}
```

I was told that if you are not planning to inherit from this class, there is no need to expose the member variables in the header file.

```
std::string m_message;
m_array_type m_recv_buf;
```

What is the option to do this without exposing the private member variables in the header files.? what are the advantages of such a method.

Comment: The right rule is:  if your code does not need to know the `sizeof()` your class, you do NOT need to include that header file - a forward declaration is sufficient.  You may increase the opacity of your class by using pimpl (or its equivalent), but ultimately, private members will show up somewhere else in your code, because the compiler will need to know the sizeof() your (other) class.

Comment: The main functional advantage of not having private members in a client-facing header is that they can then be changed without needing to recompile all the dependent client code: typically, you'll just have to recompile your own library code, then relink the client code, which is normally faster and more convenient.  This becomes more significant when lots of other people/apps are using your library.

Answer (score 3):

That is not quite correct. There are techniques that are more advanced (like a pimpl idiom or a virtual base class), but for normal usage they have to be in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

The way of doing this is to move the private variables to the `.cpp` file. Any static global variables in a translation unit are essentially "private" because they cannot be accessed from other files. The rationale (from what I can tell) is that there's less cognitive load when you're reading the header file for a synopsis.

Comment: It's not quite so simple, if the private variables are class members then there is a separate variable per class instance